# Journal out of order

Tags: linux, ubuntu, journald

Trying to figure out what caused one of our servers (Ubuntu 18.04) to become unresponsive, I was looking through the journal ( `journalctl -r`) and saw strangely out of order timestamps

```
Apr 17 09:20:19 myserver kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xca, date = 2019-10-03
-- Reboot --
Apr 15 12:58:16 myserver chronyd[1488]: Selected source 139.199.214.202
Apr 15 13:42:34 myserver systemd-resolved[1039]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 17 07:19:04 myserver sssd[11733]: ldb: unable to dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ldb/modules/ldb/samba/dsdb_notification.so : libsamdb-common.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object
```

When I look in /var/log/syslog, I see potentially the same log, but with a different timestamp

```
Apr 17 07:36:18 myserver chronyd[1488]: Selected source 139.199.214.202
```

This is probably completely unrelated to the system becoming unresponsive, but I'm just curious how this is even possible, so I can understand better.